# Not receving parameter value

Tags: node.js, express

I am using express to add/update/delete the data on MongoDB. Good think is its working fine.

**Updated**

```
function UpData(chk, _action, up){
    Employee.updateOne( chk ,{ _action : up})
      .then(data => {
        if (!data) {
            res.status(404).send({
            message: `Cannot update Employee with id=${id}. Maybe Employee was not found!`
          });
        } else res.send({ message: "Absence is added successfully." });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        res.status(500).send({
          message: "Error updating Employee with id=" + id
        });
      });

}
```

This isn't working, ca anybody help if I doing any mistake with syntax?

I guess the issue action, when I tried add console.log in function before update:

```
console.log( chk ,{ _action : up})
console.log(_action)
```

Output:

```
{ _id: '691fa64', 'absences.ab_id': 'MEk' } { _action: { 'absences.$.ab_comments': { comment: 'K1' } } }
 
 $push
```

**The question** why in both console.log action value $push didnt print?

Comment: By "not working", what do you mean? Is there an error message?

Comment: Hi @Luke not even receiving any error, more I can see the console output before calling function also I add _ in action.

Comment: What is your expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### New

```js
const updateEmployee = (id, body, chk, cb) => {
    Employee.updateOne(
        { '_id': id, 'absences.ab_id': body.id }, chk
    ).then(data => {
        if (!data) {
            return cb(`Cannot update Employee with id=${id}. Maybe Employee was not found!`);
        } else {
            return cb(null, "Absence is added successfully.");
        };
      })
      .catch(err => {
        return cb(`Error updating Employee with id=${id}`)
      });
}


exports.update = (req, res) => {
    if (!req.body) {
        return res.status(400).send({
            message: "Data to update can not be empty!"
        });
    }

    const id = req.params.id;
    if (req.body.iscom) {
        if (req.body.isadd) {
            console.log(id, req.body);
            updateEmployee(id, req.body, { '$push': { 'absences.$.ab_comments': req.body.arr } }, (err, message) => {
                if (err) {
                    res.status(404).send({
                        message: err
                    });
                }
                res.send({message});
            });
        } else {
            console.log(id, req.body);
            updateEmployee(id, req.body, { '$push': { 'absences.$.ab_comments': req.body.arr } }, (err, message) => {
                if (err) {
                    res.status(404).send({
                        message: err
                    });
                }
                res.send({message});
            });
        }
    }
}
```

### Old

```js
exports.update = (req, res) => {
    if (!req.body) {
        return res.status(400).send({
            message: "Data to update can not be empty!"
        });
    }

    const id = req.params.id;
    if (req.body.iscom) {
        if (req.body.isadd) {
            console.log(id, req.body)
            Employee.updateOne({ '_id': id, 'absences.ab_id': req.body.id }, { '$push': { 'absences.$.ab_comments': req.body.arr } })
                .then(data => {
                    if (!data) {
                        res.status(404).send({
                            message: `Cannot update Employee with id=${id}. Maybe Employee was not found!`
                        });
                    } else res.send({ message: "Absence is added successfully." });
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    res.status(500).send({
                        message: "Error updating Employee with id=" + id
                    });
                });
        }
        else {
            console.log(id, req.body)
            Employee.updateOne({ '_id': id, 'absences.ab_id': req.body.id }, { '$pull': { 'absences.$.ab_comments': req.body.arr } })
                .then(data => {
                    if (!data) {
                        res.status(404).send({
                            message: `Cannot update Employee with id=${id}. Maybe Employee was not found!`
                        });
                    } else res.send({ message: "Absence is added successfully." });
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    res.status(500).send({
                        message: "Error updating Employee with id=" + id
                    });
                });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to give `[]` to the varible which not print value, as below

```
console.log( chk ,{ [_action] : up})
```